# Python grouping elements in a list in increasing size

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
my_list = [my_list[int((i**2 + i)/2):int((i**2 + 3*i + 3)/2)] for i in range(int((-1 + (1 + 8*len(my_list))**0.5)/2))]
```

Is there a neater solution to grouping the elements of a list into subgroups of increasing size than this?

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] --> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
[1, 2, 3, 4] --> [[1], [2, 3]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] --> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

**EDIT**

Here are the results from `timeit`:

```
from timeit import Timer
from itertools import count

def martijn(it):
    it = iter(it)
    return list([next(it) for _ in range(s)] for s in count(1))

def mathematical(it):
    upper_bound = int(((1 + 8*len(it))**0.5 + 1)//2)
    return [it[i*(i-1)//2:i*(i+1)//2] for i in range(1, upper_bound)]

def time(test, n):
    a = Timer(lambda: martijn(test)).timeit(n)
    b = Timer(lambda: mathematical(test)).timeit(n)
    return round(a, 3), round(b, 3)

>>> for i in range(8):
        loops = 10**max(0, (6-i))
        print(time([n for n in range(10**i)], loops), loops)
(6.753, 4.416) 1000000
(1.166, 0.629) 100000
(0.366, 0.123) 10000
(0.217, 0.036) 1000
(0.164, 0.017) 100
(0.157, 0.017) 10
(0.167, 0.021) 1
(1.749, 0.251) 1
>>> for i in range(8):
        loops = 10**max(0, (6-i))
        print(time(range(10**i), loops), loops)
(6.721, 4.779) 1000000
(1.184, 0.796) 100000
(0.367, 0.173) 10000
(0.218, 0.051) 1000
(0.202, 0.015) 100
(0.178, 0.005) 10
(0.207, 0.002) 1
(1.872, 0.005) 1
```

Comment: Good Lord. For the sake of Python's philosophy, I sincerely hope so.

Comment: What's the pattern you're trying to achieve here? Should each sublist be 1 element longer than the previous sublist?

Comment: @2rs2ts : Yes. I will add more examples.

Comment: There's certainly a more readable way, that's for sure.

Comment: If that's the case, why is your calculation for the sublist slice so elaborate? Seems it could be simpler...

Comment: @Scorpion_God, just to clarify, ```4``` is intentionally left out in th esecond example because it does not "fit" into the scheme, right?

Comment: @wnnmaw That is correct.

Comment: @Scorpion_God What if the `4` stays? I mean, can it be there as the last item in the output?

Comment: @thefourtheye Why would the `4` want to stay? The groups need to be in increasing size in steps of `1`. The `4` will feel outnumbered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a generator expression:

```
from itertools import count

try:
    _range = xrange
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    _range = range


def incremental_window(it):
    """Produce monotonically increasing windows on an iterable.

    Only complete windows are yielded, if the last elements do not form
    a complete window they are ignored.

    incremental_window('ABCDEF') -> ['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']
    incremental_window('ABCDE') -> ['A'], ['B', 'C']

    """
    it = iter(it)
    return ([next(it) for _ in _range(s)] for s in count(1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(incremental_window([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> list(incremental_window([1, 2, 3, 4]))
[[1], [2, 3]]
>>> list(incremental_window([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

This is a generator that'll work with any iterable, including endless iterables:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> for window in incremental_window(count()):
...     print window
...     if 25 in window:
...         break
... 
[0]
[1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

You *could* make that a one-liner with a little cheating to 'inline' the `iter()` call on your list object:

```
list([next(it) for _ in _range(s)] for it in (iter(my_list),) for s in count(1))
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting writing a function on StackOverflow.  You don't see that often enough.

Comment: is this because StopIteration errors result in the `[next(it) for _ in _range(s)]` expression not being returned?

Comment: @njzk2: The generator expression exits when `next(it)` raises `StopIteration`, yes. The exception is propagated, actually, it is `list()` that catches it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, I learnt something today! using list on a generator and generating a list have different behavior in this matter !

Comment: This is definitely the neatest answer. Accepted. I have put the timing of the two main types of solutions in the question. Although this one is neater, the mathematical one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not honestly totally clear why you want to do this, which I mention purely because there's likely a task-specific way to answer your question, but I would argue that the following is at least clearer:

```
def increasing_groups(l):
    current_size = 1
    while l:
        yield l[:current_size]
        l = l[current_size:]
        current_size += 1
```

at which point you can get it via `list(increasing_groups(some_list))`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is simple answer.

```
>>> test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> bound = int((-1 + (1 + 8 * len(test)) ** 0.5) / 2)
>>> res = [test[(i + 1) * i // 2 : (i + 1) * (i + 2) // 2] for i in xrange(bound)]
>>> res
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Because the size of each slice is an arithmetic sequence. And the equation to compute the total number of arithmetic sequence is known. So we could simply compute the begin and end index of each slice directly with that equation.

Comment: Yes, the solution is `int((-1 + (1 + 8*len(my_list))**0.5)/2)`

Comment: This produces overlapping windows: `[[1], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't work because the start of your slice is simply `i`. The slicing will look like `(0, 1) (1, 3) (2, 5)` instead of `(0, 1) (1, 3) (3, 6)`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Updated the answer. Rush for ten minutes for a PC~

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've updated the answer. I was with an iPad, and unable to test it.

Comment: On Python 3, you want to use `//` floor division to ensure that the indices are integers. And that operator will work on Python 2 as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No needed. either i or i+1 will be an even number.

Comment: @Sheng: it *is* needed, because `/` on Python 3 always produces a floating point value, which you cannot use as indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the number of items to slice with `itertools.count` and you can pick the items with `itertools.islice`.

```
# Initializations and declarations
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
from itertools import count, islice
counter, it = count(0), iter(data)

# Actual list construction
result = [[item] + list(islice(it, next(counter))) for item in it]

# Making sure that the last item of the list is consistent with the previous item
if len(result) > 1 and len(result[-1]) <= len(result[-2]): del result[-1]

print(result)
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

The important thing is

```
if len(result) > 1 and len(result[-1]) <= len(result[-2]): del result[-1]
```

this line makes sure that, the last item in the list stays only if its length is greater than the last but one.

Answer (score 1):

```
def incr_grouped(iterable):
    it, n = iter(iterable), 1
    while True:
        yield [next(it) for _ in range(n)]
        n += 1
```

The key here is that `StopIteration` exception of `next(it)` breaks the `while` loop as well. This means that you may loose the last elems which are not fitted in a group.

```
>>> list(incr_grouped('ABCDEF'))
[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
>>> list(incr_grouped([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

It can be made even more compact using `itertools`. Check [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23015602/2334951)' answer.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(n * (n - 1) / 2, n * (n + 1) / 2)
```

Gives you, according to Gauss, the start and end indices of the nth element of your new list.

Therefore

```
my_list[n * (n - 1) / 2 : n * (n + 1) / 2]
```

Is the nth element of the list, and with a bit blunt filtering:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[my_list[n * (n - 1) / 2: n * (n + 1)/ 2] for n in range(1, len(my_list)) if n * (n + 1)/ 2 <= len(my_list)]
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

A proper loop with an actual `break` would probably be better, though

### Edit

Now that I know about how `StopIteration` is caught by `list` (Thank you Martjin), a simple closing condition can be done using:

```
list(my_list[n * (n - 1) // 2: n * (n + 1) // 2] for n in count(1) if iter(my_list[n * (n + 1)/ 2:]).next() > -1)
```

Provided `-1` is lower than any item in your list. (And the floor divisions are for integer typing in python 3.)

Comment: Can't the `if` limit be folded into the `range()`? E.g. calculate the required upper limit to `n` up front.

Comment: The upper limit is `int((-1 + (1 + 8*len(my_list))**0.5)/2)`, which is the positive solution to the quadratic equation derived from `s = n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: Then use that `+ 1` instead of the upper bound of `len(my_list)` in the `range()` call, and the `if` filter can go.

Comment: `[my_list[n * (n - 1) // 2: n * (n + 1) // 2] for n in range(1, int((-1 + (1 + 8 * len(my_list)) ** 0.5) / 2) + 1)]` (with some floor division thrown in)

Comment: the floor division is not useful, as `(n * (n - 1))` is pair by definition.

Comment: @njzk2: the floor division is needed in Python 3 as the `/` operator will return float objects, regardless; you cannot use a float as an index into a list, you'll get a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: Your `iter(my_list[n * (n + 1)/ 2:]).next()` expression is evaluated *each iteration*; it'll only ever produce the first element `my_list[n * (n + 1)/ 2:]` and raises `StopIteration` once that slice is empty. Not the most elegant way of triggering the exception just to exit the generator.

Comment: I know, it's not very clean, but since you already gave a proper solution based solely on iterators, I wanted to find a way to just stop my list at the proper position, rather than filtering.

Comment: I already gave you a version with an upper bound (Scorpion_God gave you the formula) though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just want to note that you still need to explicitly convert it to an `int` because `((1 + 8*10)**0.5 - 1)//2` will return a `float`.

Comment: Yes, my version in the comments above does that.